# Filter Column Text starting with > in Spark Scala DataFrame

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I need to filter only the text that is starting from > in a column.I know there are functions startsWith & contains available for string but I need to apply it on a column in DataFrame.

```
 val dataSet = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").json(input).cace()
 dataSet.select(col = "_source.content").filter(_.startsWith(">"))
```

startsWith is not available for dataset.

Comment: what version of spark are you using?

Comment: Spark Version 2.3.0 & Scala Version 2.11.12

Comment: Spark support startWith for checking a column *values* since, at least, v1.3 are you trying to filter column names?

Comment: I have a json file which has many columns, one column "_source.content" has lot of data,I only want to get data that starts after > from that column.Hope that clears. I am trying to filter data from a specific column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, e.g.:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val df = List(
  ("1001", "[physics, chemistry]", "pass"),
  ("1001", "[biology, math]", "fail"),
  ("3002", "[economics]", "pass"),
  ("2002", "[physics, chemistry]", "fail")
).toDF("student_id", "subjects", "result")

df.filter(col("student_id").startsWith("3")).show
```

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+------+
|student_id|   subjects|result|
+----------+-----------+------+
|      3002|[economics]|  pass|
+----------+-----------+------+
```

for JSON derived input - albiet not really relevant, an example using DF and not DS (works also for DS), only minor difference for field within a structure:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val df = spark.read.json("/FileStore/tables/json_nested_4.txt")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val flattened = df.select($"name", explode($"schools").as("schools_flat"))

flattened.filter(col("name").startsWith("J")).show
flattened.filter(col("schools_flat.sname").startsWith("u")).show
```

base input and structure:

```
+-------+----------------+
|   name|    schools_flat|
+-------+----------------+
|Michael|[stanford, 2010]|
|Michael|[berkeley, 2012]|
|   Andy|    [ucsb, 2011]|
| Justin|[berkeley, 2014]|
+-------+----------------+

flattened: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, schools_flat: struct<sname: string, year: bigint>]
```

returns:

```
+------+----------------+
|  name|    schools_flat|
+------+----------------+
|Justin|[berkeley, 2014]|
+------+----------------+

+----+------------+
|name|schools_flat|
+----+------------+
|Andy|[ucsb, 2011]|
+----+------------+
```

Comment: What do I need to import for that?

Comment: Not on the DataBricks platform where many imports are standard. Try import org.apache.spark.sql.Column.

Comment: what version you running?

Comment: I tried it on textFile and it worked, spark have startsWith method but in my case I am using json file and it is giving me error.

Comment: val dataSet = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").json(input).cache()    dataSet.filter(col("_source.content").startsWith(">")).show(100,false)

Comment: There are various approaches with JSON. I would create a DF and work from there but there is from_JSON. Do your stuff and apply that to the JSON.

Comment: Its a functional language. Whether json or not you should be able to apply startsWith regardless of data. All you need is a String type.

Comment: I am trying thse but none is working,  val df = dataSet.toDF()

     df.select("_source.raw_title","_source.content").filter(_.startsWith(">")).show(100,false)
    df.filter(col("_source.content").startsWith(">")).show(50,false)
    df.select("_source.content").toString.filter(_.startsWith(">")).show

Comment: Hard for me to assess without full context

Comment: Did you understand what I am trying to say?

Comment: I will look tomorrow and run against json.

Comment: I need to sleep, so will get back tomorrow. Yes, clear now but really 2 questions, anyway.

Comment: pls supply some json examples you are using like as in here https://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/

Comment: sure,I will wait for your answer tommorow.

Comment: using JSON - actually no longer JSON, hope this helps @HussainAsghar

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not have "startsWith" function, "substring" can be used:

```
dataSet.select(col = "_source.content")
  .filter(substring($"_source.content",1,1)===">")
```

Comment: Spark does not have "substring" either.

Comment: it does, just importing "import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.substring" required: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#substring_index(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: yeah,the error goes when I import it,but I don't think so it is returning me the thing I want. I want to text that starts after >. e.g .  > I need to buy this.

Comment: after filtering, function "substring" can be used for get all after ">"

Comment: you mean the code you written above will get me the desired result?